# tf.train.Saver failing to restore checkpoint from path

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm having issues with the TensorFlow (v1.8) Saver. I'm specifying a path for the checkpoint files which works correctly for saving but raises an exception when restoring, even with the same name.

```
checkpoint_path = "/some_dir_1/some_dir_2/my-checkpoint"
saver = tf.train.Saver(save_relative_paths=True)
saver.save(sess, checkpoint_path) # This works correctly
saver.restore(sess, checkpoint_path) # This doesn't
```

The `saver.save()` method works correctly, creating the corresponding *my-checkpoint.data*, *my-checkpoint.index* and *my-checkpoint.meta* files in '/some_dir_1/some_dir_2'.

**The restoring method does not work however for the same exact path as used in the save method**. I get the following exception:

> NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for /some_dir_1/some_dir_2/my-checkpoint
>        [[Node: save/RestoreV2 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_DOUBLE, DT_DOUBLE, DT_DOUBLE], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2/shape_and_slices)]]

The weird thing is that, if instead of specifying a nested path to the checkpoint you specify the checkpoint to be in the current working directory (e.g. `saver.save(sess, './awesome-checkpoint')` & `saver.restore(sess, './awesome-checkpoint')`) it works correctly.

Has anyone else experienced this? Is this a bug of am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using the saver with the default arguments (e.g. save_relative_paths=False)? It seems it is some kind of problem with relative and absolute paths. Then it would make perfectly sense that the restore operation only works with relative paths.

Comment: @DocDriven yes, I have tried and the same thing happens :(

Comment: Instead of specifying the save path manually, you could try using `tf.train.latest_checkpoint()` as callback in your restore operation. Full code would be like `saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('/some_dir_1/some_dir_2'))`. Please note that you do only specify the folder, not the file itself.

Comment: @DocDriven tf.train.latest_checkpoint returns None on the folder

Comment: In my case, the solution was at tensorflow gpu options. Check out the issue below: https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/issues/38#issuecomment-265599695

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found a solution**. Renaming the checkpoint file and its parent directories to python naming compliant names solved the issue.

I suspect that, since checkpoint files are actually code, these and their parent directories must be named with python compliant naming. This means some characters like '[' or '-' will not work (this was my issue). Haven't confirmed this is the reason however.